# How to add a custom primary key in MongoDB document using Spring Data Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoDB entity as below.

```
public class Test {
 @Id
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private String age;
}
```

Now, instead of "id", which creates a primary key "_id" in the document; I want the name to be the primary id in my document. How can I achieve that? Please note that it is mandatory for me to keep the 'private String id' field in my class. I have already tried adding @Field("name") annotation on top of private String name, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid can't get rid of the `_id` field from a document as it is a *mandatory* field in MongoDB. You can tell the client what value to use to populate `_id`, but you cannot get rid of that field entirely.

The good news, however, is that you can just mark any field as the primary key. Just add the `@Id` annotation to the `name` field. This will internally map `name` to `_id` in the MongoDB document.

In your case, you would have to structure your document like so:

```java
public class Test {

  @Id // Maps "name" to "_id" in the MongoDB document
  private String name;

  private String id;
  private String age;

}
```

Here's the relevant page in the [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) on why `_id` *must* be the primary key:

> A field required in every MongoDB document. The _id field must have a unique value. You can think of the _id field as the document's primary key . If you create a new document without an _id field, MongoDB automatically creates the field and assigns a unique BSON ObjectId.

To learn how the Spring Boot MongoDB library maps values to `_id`, please refer to the [Spring MongoDB documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html):

> The following outlines what field will be mapped to the '_id' document field:
>
> - A field annotated with @Id (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) will be mapped to the '_id' field.
> - A field without an annotation but named id will be mapped to the '_id' field.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Tahar